# Structure text from words of triplets saved in a 2D list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, 2d

I am currently having a text with its words saved as triplets in an 2D list.

My 2D List:

```
[['Python', 'is', 'an'], ['interpreted,', 'high-level', 'and'], ['general-purpose', 'programming', 'language.'], ["Python's", 'design', 'philosophy'], ['emphasizes', 'code', 'readability'], ['with', 'its', 'notable'], ['use', 'of', 'significant'], ['whitespace.', 'Its', 'language'], ['constructs', 'and', 'object-oriented'], ['approach', 'aim', 'to'], ['help', 'programmers', 'write'], ['clear,', 'logical', 'code'], ['for', 'small', 'and'], ['large-scale', 'projects.']]
```

I am creating a Python code which picks one random set of these triplets, then tries to create a new random text by using the last 2 words and by choosing a triplet that starts with these two. Finally my program ends when 200 words are being written or none other triplet set can be chosen.

The code so far:

```
import random

with open(r'c:\\python\4_TRIPLETS\Sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '').split()
    lines = [data[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
    random.shuffle([random.shuffle(i) for i in lines])

first_triplet = random.choice(lines)
last_two = first_triplet[1:3]


output_text=[]
while True:
    candidates = [t for t in lines if t[0:2] == last_two]
    if not candidates:
        break
    
    next_triplet = random.choice(candidates)
    last_two = next_triplet[1:3]
    output_text.append(next_triplet)
```

I can't automate the repetitive procedure of searching of matches and storing them at a new list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
import sys
import os
import json

outlist = []
file_in = sys.argv[1]
file_ot = str(file_in) + ".ot"

with open(file_in, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '').split()
    lines = [data[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(data), 1)]
print("\nΧωρισμένο Κείμενο σε Λίστα Τριπλετών:\n", lines)


triplet = random.choice(lines)
last_two = triplet[1:3]

print("\nΕπιλεγμένη Τριπλέτα: \n", triplet)
print("\nΔύο Τελευταίες Λέξεις Αυτής:\n", last_two)
outlist.extend(triplet)

proc_list = lines
# first selected, remove from list
proc_list.remove(triplet)

n = 0
while True:

    n += 1
    print("\nΕπανάληψη {0}\n".format(n))

    if proc_list == 0:
        print("a")
        break

    random.shuffle(proc_list)
    
    candidates = []
    
    for element in proc_list:
        if element[:2] == last_two:
            candidates.append(element)
    
    print(candidates)

    if not candidates:
        print("b")
        break
    
    
    if len(outlist) >= 200:   
        print("c")
        break
    
    triplet = random.choice(candidates)
    outlist.append(triplet[-1])
    proc_list.remove(triplet)
    
    last_two = triplet[1:3]
    print(outlist)

with open(file_ot, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(outlist, indent=10))

print(" ".join(outlist))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function (changed some parts of the code, check comments):

```
import random

#adding ["is", "an", "experiment"] to check if it works (no other triplet were present that satisfy the condition)
lines = [['Python', 'is', 'an'], ['interpreted,', 'high-level', 'and'], ['general-purpose', 'programming', 'language.'], ["Python's", 'design', 'philosophy'], ['emphasizes', 'code', 'readability'], ['with', 'its', 'notable'], ['use', 'of', 'significant'], ['whitespace.', 'Its', 'language'], ['constructs', 'and', 'object-oriented'], ['approach', 'aim', 'to'], ['help', 'programmers', 'write'], ['clear,', 'logical', 'code'], ['for', 'small', 'and'], ['large-scale', 'projects.'], ["is", "an", "experiment"]]

first_triplet = ['Python', 'is', 'an'] # random.choice(lines)


def appendNextTriplet(output_text, lines):
    if len(output_text) >= 200:
        return output_text
    candidates = [t for t in lines if t[:2] == output_text[-2:]]
    if not candidates:
        return output_text
    next_triplet = random.choice(candidates)
    output_text += next_triplet # changed from append to concatenation, it was not correct
    return appendNextTriplet(output_text, lines)

print(appendNextTriplet(first_triplet, lines)) # ['Python', 'is', 'an', 'is', 'an', 'experiment']
```

Comment: I am receiving a syntax error at candidates:. Don't actually know why.

Comment: I used the website editor, maybe something about indentation, i'm going to check on my pc.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will put a better text input because I want to create a new text based from a collection of these triplets on a new list with 200 words maximum. Is this gonna work you think???

Comment: @AndreasKreouzos yes it should work, following the same mechanism